# Flutter android application is not running while trying to execute the command "flutter run"

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Error running Gradle:

```
Exit code 1 from: C:\Users\Ashwin\demo\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\Ashwin.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.23\descriptors\com.android.tools.external.com-intellij\intellij-core\26.0.1\da4190074d36b292f150a83ad82b6bb8\descriptor.bin
```

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Comment: do you run flutter doctor command to see if everything is installed

Comment: see this https://medium.com/@mydogtom/tip-how-to-reuse-gradle-daemon-between-android-studio-and-terminal-df5232d63f38

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to the

1. android/app/gradle/wrapper/
2. open gradle-wrapper.properties
3. then  update your gradle version as for me i  update mine  from distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip to
   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip

thanks  happy coding